# Whats the best practice to share user information across apps. Shared user defaults via App Groups or Shared Keychain?

Tags: ios, keychain, ios-app-group

Need to know the preferred way to share user information across apps. 
The options I see are:
1) Shared user defaults via App Groups
2) Shared Keychain

Not sure which one is appropriate.

Comment: keychain is more secure. If you need to store sensitive data, there is no other option.

Comment: Thanks @JurajAntas